# How do you concatenate JSONB columns in a PostgreSQL query to produce a JSONB object?

Tags: postgresql, json

I am trying to produce a specific json object output from rows of a single column of `jsonb` and I'm stuck.  Before I drop into PL/pgSQL, I wanted to ask the question here. I need to concatenate a column of JSONB into a single JSON object rather than an array.

Here's an example structure of the data I need to process (cte is data is a format I don't control):

```
with cte as (
    select   '{"apples":[{"id":25711224,"xName":"abc"},{"id":25711225,"xName":"yzx"}]}'::jsonb hdata
        union   
    select   '{"oranges":[{"id":85744212,"xName":"pop"},{"id":85744213,"xName":"ziq"}]}'::jsonb hdata
)
select 
    hdata
from 
    cte
```

Which looks like:
[image]

I want to make this JSON:

```
{
  "oranges": [
    {
      "id": 85744212,
      "xName": "pop"
    },
    {
      "id": 85744213,
      "xName": "ziq"
    }
  ],
  "apples": [
    {
      "id": 25711224,
      "xName": "abc"
    },
    {
      "id": 25711225,
      "xName": "yzx"
    }
  ]
}
```

The example has 2 rows, but I could recieve any number of rows. But I know the property name of each row (apples/oranges) will be unique, so it is really a concatenation that I want:

```
select '{"oranges":[{"id":85744212,"xName":"pop"},{"id":85744213,"xName":"ziq"}]}'::jsonb||'{"apples":[{"id":25711224,"xName":"abc"},{"id":25711225,"xName":"yzx"}]}'::jsonb
```

I've tried various groupings w/ aggregate functions, which gets me close. But not quite what I need.

Comment: `select jsonb_object_agg(k, hdata->k) from cte, lateral (select * from jsonb_object_keys(hdata)) as top_key(k);`